# Python Set Intersection on Object Attributes

Tags: python, set

I have 2 sets, each containing objects of the following class:

```
class pointInfo:
    x = 0
    y = 0
    steps = 0
```

I want to find the intersection of the two sets, but only on the x and y values.
something like:

```
def findIntersections(pointInfoSet1, pointInfoSetwire2):
    return [pointInfo for pointInfo in pointInfoSet1 if pointInfo.x, pointInfo.y in pointInfoSet2]
```

I know if you have 2 sets in python you can just do set1.intersection(set2), but that wont work in this case because I just want to find where a certain subset of the object attributes are the same, not identical objects. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are `pointInfo` objects more generally equal on just their `x` and `y`?  You could write `__eq__` and `__hash__` methods to reflect that, then set intersection will work as normal.

Comment: Yes, basically I have 2 'wire's which are a set of points, and I'm trying to find the intersection where the distance from 0,0 is the smallest, while following the wires route. So the x and y co-ordinates have about 30 intersections, but the steps are never equals. so I'm just trying to compare based on the x and y values

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that makes `Point` objects that are `Hashable` on their x and y attributes:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, step=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.step = step
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Point):
            return NotImplemented
        return (self.x, self.y) == (other.x, other.y)
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.x, self.y))
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Point(x={0.x}, y={0.y}, step={0.step})".format(self)
```

We can then put them in sets and get intersections naturally:

```
{Point(1, 1, 1), Point(2, 2)} & {Point(1, 1, 2)}
# {Point(x=1, y=1, step=2)}
```

Assuming no wire crosses itself, a better solution might be to iterate through both wires, maintaining a dict of points to steps, and outputting the sum of the steps at each intersection:

```
from itertools import chain

def stepsToIntersections(wire1, wire2):
    seen = {}
    for point in chain(wire1, wire2):
        if point in seen:
            yield point.step + seen[point]
        else:
            seen[point] = point.step

closest = min(stepsToIntersections(wire1, wire2))
```